# Help with C++ linker error

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I've been struggling with a linker error that i cant seem to figure out,
I'm implementing the bellman ford algorithm as a part of my homework.

Here's the code i've written so far,
it'd be great if someone could explain why i'm getting that error,
I've pasted my code on mozilla pastebin, the two files are
graph.h : http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1193147
and bellman_ford.cpp : http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1193148

All solutions will be most appreciated and thanks to people for taking out their valuable time to help me out.

Comment: What is the linker error that you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't implement `Vertex::Vertex()` or `Edge::Edge()` - they're only declared.

Implement them like this:

```
class Vertex
{
  private:
    char vertex_name;
  public:
    Vertex() {}
...


class Edge
{
  private:
    Vertex source,destination;
    int weight;
  public:
    Edge() {}
...
```

You'll also get errors if you include `graph.h` from more than one cpp file. You should move the bodies of your member functions into a `graph.cpp` file instead of implementing them in the header the way you do.

Comment: you've explained to me the exact source of my mistake,
i'm very grateful to you for pointing it out.
i'm relatively new to c++ and don't know how to seperate the header file and the cpp file as you've mentioned,
i'll google it and give it a try.
thanks again for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to implement the constructor of Vertex.

```
class Vertex
{
  private:
    char vertex_name;
  public:
    Vertex() { };

    Vertex(char n)
    {
      vertex_name = n;
    }
//Method signatures
    char get_name();  
};
```

Comment: thank you for taking your time out to help me out,
i really appreciate it,
i can't vote up answers yet as i dont have the necessary reputation but thanks a lot indeed.